# Upgrading to Rails 4.2 breaks Delayed::Job: Job failed to load: undefined method 'fetch_value'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Upgrading to Rails 4.2, everything working fine locally, push to production 'kaboom'. Every Delayed::Job failed with the same error.

`Job failed to load: undefined method 'fetch_value' for #. Handler: " --- YAMLYAMLYAMLYAML "`

The error message we're getting is coming from the function below, which is calling into different libraries, catching the actual error, and returning their own which makes it really difficult to debug.

```
  def payload_object
    @payload_object ||= YAML.load_dj(handler)
  rescue TypeError, LoadError, NameError, ArgumentError, SyntaxError, Psych::SyntaxError => e
    raise DeserializationError, "Job failed to load: #{e.message}. Handler: #{handler.inspect}"
  end
```

Other things that might be useful, we're only using Delayed::Job (not with Active::Job).

fetch_value is never called within delayed_job, it's an Active::Record method.

Comment: Did your delayed jobs fail in your local development environment, or only production?  What about a new delayed job in production, does that fail?

Comment: Worked fine in local development. Only breaking in production. New delayed jobs fail, as well as the ones previously created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a similar `fetch_value` error when I upgraded an app to Rails 4.2.1.  To get a closer understanding of the error, grab any job with this error and run the following in the rails console:

`YAML.load_dj(Delayed::Job.find(JOB_ID).handler)`

It runs internal delayed job code, but should give you a better trace for debugging.

source: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb#L90

The error is likely the result of queueing/creating jobs pre-Rails 4.2 upgrade and before setting `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job` in your application.rb.  If the config was not properly set, then jobs would be serialized in a format that Rails 4.2 cannot handle.  To run any jobs with the `fetch_value` error, you can switch to a branch of your code  still on > Rails 4.2 and run the jobs from the rails console.

Comment: Do we need to have "config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job" set even if we haven't set up any of the active Job infrastructure? ie. we were just using delayed job without active job (only option before 4.2)

Comment: Yes, I didn't have ActiveJob set up either, but setting `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job` seemed to be required regardless.

Comment: So the issue was that the delayed jobs were prepared under rails 3 and persisting through after the update. So I had to do nothing :|

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update delayed_job to newer version, there was a series of [changes](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for rails 4/4.2/4.4 support, and see if it brakes things in your app.

And for rails 4.2 they [expect](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#rails-42) you set `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job` in config/application.rb